# Getting different result with the same number

Tags: ios, objective-c, preprocessor-directive

I have defined to preprocessor directives:

```
#define PTM_RATIO 32
#define PTM_RATIO_2 isIPad?64:32
```

Then inside a method I use the above directives like this:

```
NSLog(@"PTM_RATIO %d",PTM_RATIO);
NSLog(@"PTM_RATIO_2 %d",PTM_RATIO_2);

float32 test=100*PTM_RATIO;
float32 test2=100*PTM_RATIO_2;

NSLog(@"Test %f",test);
NSLog(@"Test2 %f",test2);
```

Here's the output of the above code:

```
2013-03-25 23:43:57.011 Box2d[3625:15203] PTM_RATIO 32
2013-03-25 23:43:57.019 Box2d[3625:15203] PTM_RATIO_2 32
2013-03-25 23:43:57.020 Box2d[3625:15203] Test 3200.000000
2013-03-25 23:43:57.021 Box2d[3625:15203] Test2 32.000000
```

As you can see, both PTM_RATIO and PTM_RATIO_2 are 32. Then why do I get 3200.000000 when 100 is multiplied by PTM_RATIO, but 32.000000 when it's multiplied by PTM_RATIO_2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Preprocessor macros are largely text substitutions. Change:

```
#define PTM_RATIO_2 isIPad?64:32
```

to:

```
#define PTM_RATIO_2 (isIPad?64:32)
```

Without that, your source code:

```
100*PTM_RATIO_2
```

expanded to:

```
100*isIPad?64:32
```

which is then parsed as:

```
(100*isIPAD) ? 64 : 32
```

Comment: Good answer, I was just writing something similar :-)

Answer (score 1):

The PTM_RATIO_2 is evaluated as follows in real code

```
float32 test2 = (100*isIPad)?64:32;
```

You are assuming that the MACRO will evaluate prior to live code calculation.